# I want to manage database with codes in CakePHP

Tags: database, cakephp, updatemodel

I want to store "dbversion" record in "settings" table with initial value is 100.

```
public create_update_db() {
  // dbversion: 101
  // I want to dbversion value in settings table here. 
  If (value < 101) {
    -> add, alter table or somethings else about dabase;
    -> set dbversion value as 101
  }
  If (value < 102) {
    -> add, alter table or somethings else about dabase;
    -> set dbversion value as 102
  }

 // Every new db updates that I need, I'll add new lines here. 
 // And controlled all database with codes in CakePHP 

}
```

All I need where do I use "create_update_db" procedure? In App_contraller? Or where. 
This procedure have to call before any page loading...

Answer (score 0):

I believe you’re looking for schema management: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells/schema-management-and-migrations.html